# confirmation before selecting a command from bash history

Tags: bash

while I am in terminal, I can use up arrow key get the history command (e.g., `bash build.sh`), then I press enter, the bash command immediate run, So I want a confirm on a terminal.

I can glue it a each sh file, but would be better to just stop it at bash terminal level

Comment: `bash you_sh.*.sh` runs `bash you_sh.1.sh you_sh.2.sh...`, so the first script (which may be looked up in $PATH rather than running the one in the current working directory) with the names of the remaining scripts as arguments. If you wanted to run each of the matching scripts with no arguments, you'd rather do `shopt -s nullglob; for script in ./you_sh.*.sh; do bash "$script"; read -rp "Press Enter to continue"; done`

Comment: @jian thanks! I slightly shortened your question, because it seems to be very little about `bash build.sh`, but much more about the history interface. I hope I represented that clearly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
trap 'echo Are you sure running $BASH_COMMAND?; read a' DEBUG
```

Comment: can this be pattern matching. like ending with "dot sh"

Comment: `[[ $BASH_COMMAND = *.sh ]] && `